# How to configure Nginx to serve always one static file for all locations matching pattern?

Tags: nginx, react-router

I have one laravel application served over nginx, and another application just with react that creates a static site that uses only client side routing react-router.

So far so good, now I **want to achieve the following**:

all urls with pattern
**domain.com/admin/[whateverhere]** should be served the following static html file

`/var/www/html/admin_app/public/index.html` (react static admin app) instead of being handled by

`/var/www/html/users_app/public/index.php` (the laravel app)

This is my nginx configuration only for this part, that does not work but returns 404:

```
   location /admin/ {
      root /var/www/html/admin_app/public;
      index index.html;
      try_files $uri index.html;
    }
```

The rest of config is just ssl, and main domain.

I don't want the laravel app to handle /admin/projects /admin/users routes, but I want all of these to go to just that index.htlm file which is a static react app, with client side router only.

By checking nginx looks, I see that it tries to read non existing html file! not the one I specify at /var/www/html/admin_app/public/index.html

```
 2020/12/01 15:30:31 [error] 6#6: *8 open() "/etc/nginx/htmlindex.html" failed (2: No such file or directory),
```

I have no idea why nginx tries to open this /etc/nginx/htmlindex.html file...

Comment: Your `/index.html` term needs a leading `/` and cannot be the final parameter. Use: `try_files /index.html =404;`

Comment: Great ! This works very good as first step all are serving index.html. Now I am having second trouble, that is for js,images and other files I need to serve them instead of index.html. How can I use one rule for that  ? Now what happens is that for example domain/admin/js/t.js is returning content of index.html. Idea is that index.html should be returned only for routes like domain/admin/posts/33 and so on, files should be returned from real file content

Comment: Are all of the resource files in `/var/www/html/admin_app/public` and accessed using a URI that begins with `/admin/`?

Comment: @RichardSmith yes exactly they are requested like `domain/admin/static/js/main.js` They are located at `/var/www/html/admin_app/public/static/js` /static/css and so on, while index is just in public/index.html together with favicon and more stuff there

Comment: Example how the index.html is requesting the webpack chunk : `https://domain.dev/admin/static/js/main.119be1ce.chunk.js` and currently index.html is returned for everything also for this script result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two potential solutions...

First, using a regular expression `location` with a `root` and `try_files` directive:

```
location ~ ^/admin(/.*)$ {
    root /var/www/html/admin_app/public;
    try_files $1 /index.html =404;
}
```

The regular expression `location` is evaluated in order, so the placement within the configuration file is significant. Place near the beginning of the `server` block to avoid unwanted side effects. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.

Note that the `=404` is never reached, it just exists to that `/index.html` is not the last parameter of the `try_files` statement. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for details.

---

Alternatively, using a prefix `location` with an `alias` directive:

```
location ^~ /admin/ {
    alias /var/www/html/admin_app/public/;
    if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite ^ /admin/index.html last; }
}
```

Both the `location` value and `alias` value should end with a `/`, or neither end with a `/`.

The `alias` and `try_files` directives do not work well together due to [this long term issue](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/97), hence the `if` block. See [this caution](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) on the use of `if` within a `location` block.

Comment: Perfect, this is almost there!!! Assets work fine, index  works fine all routes non files go to index.html. Issue is: also urls like `domain/api/admin/approve-posts` still get handled by this location block. I need only urls like `domain/admin/.*` to be handled by that block, and urls that dont have directly after domain` /admin` should be handled by the laravel app as before, because now those broke and return 404, for example now `domain/api/admin/approve-post` returns 404 is handled by this new location block, instead should be handled by laravel block as before

Comment: Neither of the `location` blocks in my answer will match a URI beginning with `/api/admin/`. If those URIs are being redirected, it is happening elsewhere in your configuration.

Comment: I restarted proxy now worked correctly with second variation, using alias matched only stuff starting with /admin directly after domain, and all others like /api/admin or whatever/admin handled by next locations the laravel app. Thanks a lot, marked as the answer great solution