# scribe 403 Forbidden nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, scribe

I've try to access my api documentation on our staging environment but I got 403 forbidden error. I'm using nginx as a webserver.

[image: 404 Forbidden]

Here's what I have tried so far but didn't work.

1. nginx configuration.

   server {
   server_name my_domain;
   root /var/www/my_domain/public;

   add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
   add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
   add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

   index index.html index.htm index.php;

   charset utf-8;

   location / {
   try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
   }

   location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
   location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

   error_page 404 /index.php;

   location ~ .php$ {
   fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
   fastcgi_index index.php
   fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
   include fastcgi_params;
   }

   location ~ /.(?!well-known).* {
   allow all;
   }

   listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
   ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/dev.vibestrive.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
   ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/dev.vibestrive.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
   include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
   ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}

2. `chmod -R 775 public/docs`

Accessing generated api documentation is not included in scribe documentation.
If anyone had successfully implemented it on the ubuntu server please comment down below. Thanks.

Comment: You might need to specify `location` for `docs/` folder. Something like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65107541/3226121). Check also [nginx docs for Serving Static Content](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/serving-static-content/)

Comment: Are you using laravel ?